# BNF grammar mimicking Java method declarations

Tags: java, bnf

How can I write a [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) grammar mimicking Java method declarations?

Here's what I have:

```
<call> ::= <return-type> <method-identifier>(<parameter-list>);
<return-type> ::= void | <type>
<type> ::= byte | short | int | long | float | double | boolean | char
<parameter-list> ::= <parameter> | <parameter>,<parameter-list>
<parameter> ::= <type> <parameter-identifier>
```

Do I have the right idea? Is this the correct form for BNF? This won't be implemented for anything, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the idea.

Comment: The idea is right, but some things are missing: a parameter list can also be empty, and a type can also be something else than a primitive type or `void`.

Comment: Aren't you talking about method declarations here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going in a good direction. However, `type` doesn't allow class names (in Java you can pass objects as parameters). And you are missing `throws` block and it doesn't allow arrays.

Why don't you compare with [the actual BNF grammar for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html)?